# VBoxManage: how to get VM's runtime information/statistics

Tags: virtualbox

I’d like to know the number of bytes read/written since VM started.
It is possible in VirtualBox GUI's menu, 
`Machine -> Session Information` shows a neat window with the info I need:

[image]

But I cannot find a way to do the same with VBoxManage.
Neither `metrics` nor `guestproperty` seems to provide the stats.
`debugvm info`  looked promising,  it yields a lot of cryptic data but not the figures I am looking for. I might have missed something though.
I'm basically interested in disk IO statistics, but network stats would be fine to know too

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-metrics

Comment: @ajgringo619, metrics seem to require the additions to be installed, also the only disk related metric on my machine is `Disk/Usage/Used`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have figured out it by myself. The aswer is `debugvm statistics`.
It outputs xml but for simplicity I'll use grep:

```
MinGW$ VBoxManage debugvm $MY_VM statistics | grep name=\"/Devices.\*Bytes\"
<Counter c="1184613888" unit="bytes" vis="used" name="/Devices/AHCI0/Port0/ReadBytes"/>
<Counter c="331036672" unit="bytes" vis="used" name="/Devices/AHCI0/Port0/WrittenBytes"/>
<Counter c="184550400" unit="bytes" vis="used" name="/Devices/AHCI0/Port1/ReadBytes"/>
<Counter c="396939264" unit="bytes" vis="used" name="/Devices/AHCI0/Port1/WrittenBytes"/>
<Counter c="1079296" unit="bytes" vis="used" name="/Devices/AHCI0/Port2/ReadBytes"/>
<Counter c="331808713" unit="bytes" name="/Devices/E1k0/ReceiveBytes"/>
<Counter c="19335791" unit="bytes" name="/Devices/E1k0/TransmitBytes"/>
```

The entries with `AHCI` in their names are SATA disks, `E1k0` is apparently a network adapter